# How can I rerender a repeater

Tags: visualforce

I want to rerender the contents of a repeater using jquery but it doesn't seem to be working any ideas?

Visualforce code:

```
<script>
  $(function() {  

        alert(1);
        rerenderDevelopmentPanel();
        alert(2);        
  });
  </script>
</head>  

<apex:Form >
<apex:pageBlock Title="Cases">
<apex:actionFunction name="rerenderDevelopmentPanel" rerender="DevelopmentPanel" />

  <apex:pageBlockSection title="Development" collapsible="true" columns="3">
    <div class="sectionContainer">

     <apex:outputPanel id="DevelopmentPanel">
        <apex:repeat value="{!CasesMap['Development']}" var="listvalue" id="DevelopmentRepeater">
            <div class="cardSquare" style="background-color:lightgreen;" id="{!listvalue.Id}" >
               <a href="/{!listvalue.Id}">{!listvalue.CaseNumber}</a>
               <br/><b>{!listvalue.Subject}</b>
               <br/><br/>{!listvalue.Description}<br/><br/>                
           </div>
        </apex:repeat>
        </apex:outputPanel>
     </div>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Controller code:
public class CaseController
{

```
public static Map<String, List<Case>> getCasesMap()
{
    Map<String, List<Case>> casesMap = new Map<String, List<Case>>();
    List<Case> developmentCases = new List<Case>(); 
    List<Case> testingCases = new List<Case>(); 
    List<Case> roadblockedCases = new List<Case>(); 
    List<Case> doneCases = new List<Case>(); 
    for(Case caseItem : [select Id, Subject, Description, Status, CaseNumber from Case])
    {
        if(caseItem.Status == 'Development')
        {
            developmentCases.add(caseItem);
        }
        if(caseItem.Status == 'Testing')
        {
            testingCases.add(caseItem);
        }
        if(caseItem.Status == 'Roadblocked')
        {
            roadblockedCases.add(caseItem);
        }
        if(caseItem.Status == 'Done')
        {
            doneCases.add(caseItem);
        }            

        System.debug('status:' + caseItem.Status + ' Id:' + caseItem.Id);
    }  
    casesMap.put('Development', developmentCases);        
    casesMap.put('Testing', testingCases); 
    casesMap.put('Roadblocked', roadblockedCases);
    casesMap.put('Done', doneCases);   
    return casesMap;
}
```

Not all the code is here but you get the idea. The Javascript function gets called and both alert 1 and 2 fire but the rerender of the repeater doesn't seem to happen. I was expecting it to call the controller's getCasesMap function again and rebuild the cases on the screen. Instead nothing happens.

Thanks and any help is appreciate.

-Adam

Comment: Have you missed the `action` of the `actionFunction` when posting or it's not there?

Comment: Question for question, whats the point of JS here? Why can't you use standard rendered?

Comment: @highfive You should post that as an answer, seems likely!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see both `alert(1)` and `alert(2)` since there may not any script errors. Which means yes it's calling to your `actionFunction` as well. But the problem is you don't have an `action` parameter in your `actionFunction`. without `action` parameter it won't call the controller and so framework doesn't think of a rerender. So simply add it and try.

```
<apex:actionFunction action="{!getCasesMap}" name="rerenderDevelopmentPanel" rerender="DevelopmentPanel"/>
```

I'm assuminig that you need to call the controller method at page loading and for that using this `actionFuntion`. If not I don't see a special usage of having an `actionFunction` here(in the posted portion of your code). But for this case also may be you should try the `action` parameter of the `page` itself.

Comment: Thanks highfive that was it didn't have the action defined! Thanks to Lacey also

Comment: Glad to help you. Yes, @LaceySnr's points also very important. To be honest I'd like if you and me follow the `id` format(dot notation with the hierarchy) that he has mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

First up, your question doesn't have an `action` parameter in the `<apex:actionFunction>` tag which means no controller code is getting called; if that is the case (and it's not a posting issue) then hopefully @highfive will answer and can be voted up, if it's not the case then here's some things to try.

I'm assuming you just missed the `action` parameter while posting in which case the issue might just because of the page structure you've got in place. Maybe try the following (added ID to the `<apex:pageBlockSection>`:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="rerenderDevelopmentPanel" rerender="section.DevelopmentPanel"  action="{!getCasesMap}"/>

<apex:pageBlockSection title="Development" collapsible="true" columns="3" id="section">
  <div class="sectionContainer">
    <apex:outputPanel id="DevelopmentPanel">
```

If that fails you might have better luck putting the `<apex:actionFunction>` right next to the panel itself:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Development" collapsible="true" columns="3" id="section">
  <div class="sectionContainer">
    <apex:actionFunction name="rerenderDevelopmentPanel" rerender="section.DevelopmentPanel" action="{!getCasesMap}"/>
    <apex:outputPanel id="DevelopmentPanel">
```

Finally, sounds silly but I've done it before, make sure that something being rerendered is actually being changed by the controller :)